# parsing image with json to ListView beside text

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-asynctask

I'm working on an app which require to get the new titles and add thumb images beside them in listView and I don't know how to convet the photos url to images and put in the listView I made here's the code :

I can get the image url but I don't know what to do to add to the listView beside the text I got, any help ?

```
    private class theJob extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>{




    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, result, R.layout.list_item,
                   new String[] {TAG_CAT_NAME }, new int[] {R.id.label });
          setListAdapter(adapter);
          Log.d("adapter", "works");

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
            String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Format", params[0]);
        Log.d("URL", params[1]);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> cat = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        JsonParser jparser = new JsonParser();
        Log.d("url", "to the other class");
        JSONArray jArray = jparser.getJSONfronUrl(params[1]);
           Log.d("json array", "created");
           try{
                for(int i=0 ; i< jArray.length()  ; i++){
                   JSONObject joob = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   Log.d("jobj", "done");
                   String title = joob.getString(params[0]);
                   Log.d(TAG_CAT_NAME, "done");
                   cat_id = joob.getString(TAG_CAT_ID);
                   Log.d(TAG_CAT_ID, cat_id); 
                   cat_url.add(i, joob.getString(TAG_CAT_URL)) ;
                   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                   map.put(params[0], title);

                   cat.add(map);
               }

           }catch(JSONException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           Log.d("Going to ADAPTER", "working");
           return cat;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a googe [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) this will help you what you want :)

**Update**

Here you will fine more help about Lazy loading of images in [list view](http://evancharlton.com/thoughts/lazy-loading-images-in-a-listview).

Comment: Thanks .. it actually works but that drove me to another problem 
the imageloader.java doesn't return images back when I call the lazyadapter.java from the my ( the job extends AsyncTask .. ) class ..
I don't know why !!

Comment: didn't help actually .. I still can't do it

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of SmartImageView, it is a drop-in replacement for Android’s standard ImageView which additionally allows images to be loaded from URLs or the user’s contact address book. Images are cached to memory and to disk for super fast loading.

https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view